# Topological space generated by a segment of a curve inside of $\mathrm{SL}(n,\Bbb R)$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups

I am interested in to see what is the topological space generated by a segment of a curve inside of $\mathrm{SL}(n,\Bbb R)$? i.e. Suppose $A\neq B\in \mathrm{SL}(n,\Bbb R)$  and $\gamma$ an arbitrary path in $\mathrm{SL}(n,\Bbb R)$ joining these two points such that $\gamma$ does not lay entirely in $\mathrm{SO}(n)$. Then what is the space generated by segment $\gamma$? i.e.
$$\langle\gamma \rangle=\{C_1^{n_1}C_2^{n_2}\dots C_k^{n_k}\  |\ C_i\in\gamma, n_i\in\Bbb Z, k\in \Bbb N\}?$$

How to prove that this space is connected?

I think this space should be all of $\mathrm{SL}(n,\Bbb R)$. But I don't know how. By the above definition, actually it is a group because $C^s\in \langle\gamma \rangle$ and $C^{-s}\in \langle\gamma \rangle$ and $I=C^0\in \langle\gamma \rangle$.

Comment: What do you mean by *subspace generated by the segment*? To the generation of what kind of (sub)spaces are you referring? The way the right-hand side of the definition you furnished looks, you seem to be considering the subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ generated by the image $\mathrm{Im}\gamma$ of your path...

Comment: Yes, I meant subgroup as a Lie group if it is.

Comment: Given an arbitrary topological group $(G, \cdot, \mathscr{T})$ and a *connected* subset such that $1_G \in X \subseteq G$, then the subgroup $\langle X \rangle$ it generates is also connected.

Comment: Ok, so it remain to know what the space is.

Comment: To what space are you referring to?

Comment: Are you sure about your previous comment? I remember that I read somewhere that if $1\in U$ and $U$ being open is required. Isn't?

Comment: This space $\langle\gamma \rangle$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116234/discussion-between--and-c-f-g).

Comment: One can prove that this way you can obtain any connected subgroup of $SL(n,R)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: You meant that there are many Lie subgroup of $G\leq \mathrm{SL}(n,\Bbb R)$ of positive dimension such that we can consider $\gamma\subset G$? any such example?

Comment: Right. For instance, in case $n=2$ you will get the group of (positive) diagonal matrices as well as the group of upper triangular matrices (with positive diagonal entries).

Comment: Well, Now what about proof of connectedness?

Comment: Connectedness is rather straightforward if the arc contains 1, but is false in general. (What Leo wrote is based on misunderstanding of the question.) Moreover, not every disconnected (even closed) Lie subgroup of $SL(n,R)$ can be generated by an arc.

Comment: Here the arc does not contains the $id$ in general but $\langle\gamma \rangle$ does. So it is not connected as you commented?

Comment: Yes, and examples are easy to construct by taking $\gamma\subset G< SL(n,R)$, where $G$ is a disconnected subgroup and $\gamma$ is contained in a component of $G$ which is not the connected component of the identity. To be concrete, take $n=2$, and $G$ the group of all diagonal matrices and $\gamma$ contained in the subset of matrices in $G$ with negative diagonal entries.

Answer (score 0):

The space you are looking for is a submonoid of SL$(n,{\mathbb{R}})$.
It contains at least two elements.

Note that if $A = I$ (the identity matrix) then $\langle \gamma \rangle = \langle B \rangle = \{ B^{n}, \ n \in {\mathbb{Z}} \}$ which is distinct from SL$(n, {\mathbb{R}})$. So your conjecture is wrong in general.

I take a path in SL$(n, {\mathbb{R}})$ from $A$ to $B$ to mean a continuous map $\gamma:[0,1] \to {\rm{SL}}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\gamma(0) = A$ and $\gamma(1) = B$. Since SL$(n, {\mathbb{R}})$ is connected, there is always such a path.

Now fix such a map. Then $\langle \gamma \rangle = \{ \gamma(t)\cdot \gamma(t') \ | \ t, t' \in [0,1] \}$. Thus $\langle \gamma \rangle$ is the image by the
map
$$ [0,1] \times [0,1] \to {\rm{SL}}(n,{\mathbb{R}}), \ (t,t') \mapsto \gamma(t) \cdot \gamma(t').$$
This map is continuous and $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ is connected, so $\langle \gamma \rangle$ is also connected.

Comment: You meant $\langle \gamma \rangle = \langle B \rangle = \{ B^{n}, \ n \in {\mathbb{Z}} \}$ by $\langle \gamma \rangle = \langle A \rangle = \{ A^{n}, \ n \in {\mathbb{Z}} \}$?

Comment: Also, I think it is not true that $\langle \gamma \rangle = \langle B \rangle = \{ B^{n}, \ n \in {\mathbb{Z}} \}$ for $A=I$.

Comment: Ok after you edited it, $\gamma$ is now by definition a subgroup of SL$(n,{\mathbb{R}})$.

Comment: Actually before my edit (sorry for bad question and edit) your climes was wrong about $\langle \gamma \rangle = \langle B \rangle$